# CHMOD - Applying Different Permissions For Files vs. Directories

Tags: permissions, chmod

I've been trying to clean up permissions on a few boxes and have been scouring the chmod man as well as all the internet documentation that I an handle without any luck -- so here we go.

Basically, I've got a directory with many sub directories and files -- and I'd like to set the following permissions:

For directories: 770 (u+rwx, g+rwx, o-rwx)

For files: 660 (U+rw, g+rw, a-x, o-rw)

I'd like to try and do this with a single recursive chmod if possible -- as to avoid recursing through each directory and setting file-by-file permissions.

I imagine there's got to be a way to do this without writing a shell script of my own -- but I haven't been able to find anything.

I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I do find a script useful since it's often useful to change both file and directory permissions in one swoop, and they are often linked. 770 and 660 for shared directories on a file server, 755/644 for web server directories, etc. I keep a script w/ the most commonly used mode for that type of server in root's bin/ and just do the find manually when the common mode doesn't apply.

```
#!/bin/sh
# syntax: setperm.s destdir
#
if [ -z $1 ] ; then echo "Requires single argument: <directoryname>" ; exit 1 ;                                       fi

destdir=$1

dirmode=0770
filemode=0660

YN=no

printf "\nThis will RECURSIVELY change the permissions for this entire branch:\n                                      "
printf "\t$destdir\n"
printf "\tDirectories chmod = $dirmode\tFiles chmod = $filemode\n"
printf "Are you sure want to do this [$YN]? "

read YN

case $YN in
        [yY]|[yY][eE][sS])
        # change permissions on files and directories.
        find $destdir -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod $filemode $i
        find $destdir -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod $dirmode $ii ;;

        *) echo "\nBetter safe than sorry I always say.\n" ;;
esac
```

Comment: Wow! This is exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you very much!

Comment: Hey iPaulo -- can you by chance explain the "$ii" on the line "find $destdir -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod $dirmode $ii ;;".   I'm not sure I understand why its not just "find $destdir -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod $dirmode $i ;;"

Thanks!

Answer (score 27):

No need for scripts.

// Directories:

```
find . -type d -exec chmod 770 '{}' \;
```

// Files:

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 660 '{}' \;
```

Answer (score 23):

In your case it might not have to be as complicated as others has made it out to be (though `find` is indeed a good tool for this sort of thing in general). The difference between the modes are the execute bit. If it is the case that no files already has the execute bit set, then you can do it in a single invocation of `chmod`, just as you asked.

```
chmod -R u=rwX,g=rwX,o= FILE...
```

The key here is the capital `X`, which the man page explains as

> execute/search only if the file is a directory or already has execute permission for some user.

Thus, if your files do not already have the execute bit set, it will only be set for directories.

Comment: This is great, but much longer than just writing 777.  Is there a shorthand for the -X ?

Answer (score 7):

I found that for my use case at least, using `rsync` to copy the directory onto itself was much faster than using `chmod` directly with a list of files from `find`.

```
rsync -rpt --chmod=D770,F660 . .
```

If you want to add a `chown` to the same operation, `rsync` lets you do that too with the `--chown=user:group` option.

Comment: Whoah, this actually a lot faster than chmod -R.

Comment: So much faster than chmod. Are there any downsides to using rsync this way? I've been doing it a lot and everything seems fine.

Comment: It's also worth noting that if you want to use the `--chown` option you'll also need to add the `-o` and `-g` flags. That seems a little counter-intuitive but `--chown` is shorthand for some other more verbose options, and those options don't have any effect if `-o` and `-g` are missing.

Answer (score 1):

Clean and simple:

```
chmod 660 $(find . -type f)
chmod 770 $(find . -type d)
```

Comment: Very elegant approach.

Comment: perhaps, but note that this only works if the files have no spaces in them. A more "safe" approach is `find ... -exec chmod ... {} \;`